# Find/Allocate IP to new VM for ssh

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

I created a virtualbox vm with bridge connection. How do I find its IP address, or set its IP, so I can ssh into it and use it?

It has a mac address, can I use this at all to set a route through arp ?

Comment: Did you try running arp -an on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VM template that has EUI-64 addressing on interfaces. Set or get a known MAC address. IPv6 address will be your prefix + computed EUI-64.

AAAA records can be entered in DNS as soon as the MAC address is known.